# Dynamic Multiple Dropdown Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to know is it possible to do a dynamic dropdown list. Let say I `got 3 dynamic dropdown` that have a value of three user and I want it to be flexile.

`e.g`:

```
dropdown1 : UserA, UserB and UserC

dropdown2 : UserA, UserB and UserC

dropdown3 : UserA, UserB and UserC
```

`if selected from dropdown1 = UserC,
dropdown2 and dropdown3 will list out the remaining user UserA and UserB,
and at the same time when selected from dropdown3 = UserA then the dropdown1 listed 2 user = UserB and UserC and dropdown2 will list only 1 user UserB.`

I know it's big tricky, but is it possible to create with the javascript or using AJAX?

Comment: Anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, you may need to add logic to add unselected item when someone selects the first item again

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <FORM name="addproductfrm" id="addproductform" method="POST" action="/storeproduct">
            <select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1" onchange="removeSelectedItem(this)">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="User A">User A</option>
                <option value="User B">User B</option>
                <option value="User C">User C</option>
            </select>

            <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2" onchange="removeSelectedItem(this)">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="User A">User A</option>
                <option value="User B">User B</option>
                <option value="User C">User C</option>
            </select>

            <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2" onchange="removeSelectedItem(this)">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="User A">User A</option>
                <option value="User B">User B</option>
                <option value="User C">User C</option>
            </select>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function removeSelectedItem(selectedItem)
    {
        var selectedValue = selectedItem.options[selectedItem.selectedIndex].value
        console.log(selectedValue);
        var selectBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

        for (var i=0; i < selectBoxes.length; i++)
        {
            var curValue = selectBoxes[i].options[selectBoxes[i].selectedIndex].value

            for (var j=1; j < selectBoxes[i].options.length; j++)
            {
                if (j != selectBoxes[i].selectedIndex && selectBoxes[i].options[j].value == selectedValue)
                    selectBoxes[i].remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Great,
but when the dropdown1 after selected set it back to -- Select -- the value not recalculate back at dropdown2 and dropdown3.

Comment: Yes, I know that and mention in my answer too. You have to remember the last value of current select box and if its value changed to --select--, then add the last value to all comboboxes if they are not present

Comment: ok got it, i had try by using a jquery with some modification from urs javascript
<script>
  var prevVal;

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('[id^=dropdown]').click(function(){
    prevVal = $(this).val();
   });
   
   $('[id^=dropdown]').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("dropdown","");
    var val = $(this).val();

    for(var i=1; i<$('[id^=dropdown]').size()+1; i++){
     if(i!=id){
      if(val!="0") $('[id=dropdown'+i+'] option[value="'+val+'"]').hide();            
      $('[id=dropdown'+i+'] option[value="'+prevVal+'"]').show();}}});});</script>

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
    Select User:<select name="userSelect" id="first">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="userA">userA</option>
    <option value="userB">userB</option>
    <option value="userC">userC</option>
    </select>
    Select User:<select name="userSelect" id="second">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="userA">userA</option>
    <option value="userB">userB</option>
    <option value="userC">userC</option>
    </select>
    Select User:<select name="userSelect" id="third">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="userA">userA</option>
    <option value="userB">userB</option>
    <option value="userC">userC</option>
    </select>

     <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("select[name=userSelect]").change(
     function() {
     var all = [];
     var arrId=$("select[name=userSelect]");
     for(i=0;i<arrId.length;i++){
    //alert($(arrId[i]).attr('id'));
    all.push($(arrId[i]).attr('id'));
     }

    var index = all.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
    all.splice(index, 1);
    for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){
    $('#'+all[i]+'').find("[value="+$(this).val()+"]").remove();
    }
   //var selectId=$(this).attr('id');
    //var selectedVal=$(this).val();
    //alert( $(this).val());
            });
     });

   </script>
```

.But its not recalculating values as you mentioned try to change the same....